# Presto: How to map arrays of different length?

Tags: presto, trino

Say I have arrays `['1', '2', '3']` and `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']` and I want to map them

```
select map(array ['1', '2', '3'], array ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
```

This will return an error saying that the arrays need to be of the same length.

How can I replicate the python's `zip()` which drops the ones without a pair? Or if not, pad the missing ones with NULLs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `slice` and `cardinality` to "fix" sizes:

```sql
WITH dataset AS (
  SELECT * 
  FROM 
    (
      VALUES 
        (ARRAY [1, 2, 3], ARRAY[1, 2, 3, 4])
    ) AS t (arr1, arr2)
) 

SELECT 
  map (
    slice(arr1, 1, m), 
    slice(arr2, 1, m)
  ) 
FROM 
  (
    SELECT *, LEAST(cardinality(arr1), cardinality(arr2)) as m 
    FROM 
      dataset
  )
```

Output:

| _col0 |
| --- |
| {1=1, 2=2, 3=3} |

Or just use `zip` and transform the resuting array of `ROW`'s into map (note, this relies on default naming convention for elements of `ROW`, as [@Martin Traverso](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2958752/martin-traverso) points out in comments in Trino  you can access row fields by index, so you can change corresponding line to `r -> r[1] IS NOT NULL`):

```sql
WITH dataset AS (
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES   
       (ARRAY [1,2,3], ARRAY[1,2,3,4])
 ) AS t (arr1, arr2))

SELECT map_from_entries(filter(zip(arr1, arr2), r -> r.field0 is not NULL))
FROM dataset
```

Output:

| _col0 |
| --- |
| {1=1, 2=2, 3=3} |

Comment: In Trino (formerly known as Presto SQL), you can access row fields by index to avoid relying on the default naming, which is an implementation detail and subject to change: `r -> r[1] IS NOT NULL`

Comment: @MartinTraverso great news! When writing something similar for the first time indexer was the first thing I have tried, unfortunately I'm using Athena though and it does not support it =(